# Calling a python script from another script and passing variables to it

Tags: python

I have a python script that contains a large function that filters a list and exports the contents to excel. I want to be able to make different python scripts where I can specify different filters for different cases and pass them to my python scripts with the function that applies the filter.

For example

```
#Script called function_script with function to apply filters
def my_funct(filter1, filter2, filter3, etc):
    apply filters to list
    export results to excel
```

I will have different filters for some common use cases and instead of changing my filters I would rather create a python script for each use case that calls the script containing my functions and passes the filters. Something like.

```
#One script where filters for category 1 are defined
filter1 = 'Foo'
filter2 = 'Bar'
filter3 = 'Test'
function_script(filter1, filter2, filter3)
```

Comment: import the script with function ?

Comment: Do you mean I can simply just do `import function_script` and then use it? Do they need to be in the same working directory? To pass variables to it would it just simply be `function_script(filter1, filter2, filter3)?

Comment: Assuming `function_script` is in `function_file.py`, if the two files are in the same directory it would be `from function_file import function_script`

Comment: You can import it as: `from function_script import my_funct`, and then use `my_funct(filter1, filter2, filter3)`, or you can use `import function_script as f` and call the method as `f.my_funct(filter1, filter2, filter3)`. I recommend the second method, since it's easier to use with multiple functions.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that file with large function is in one directory with all others :

```
some folder
|-functions_file.py
|-main.py
```

So your functions file will contain your functions for example :

```
def add(num1, num2):
    return num1+num2

def subtract(num1, num2):
    return num1-num2

#here is example function to show you how to pass more values to function
def add_all(numbers):
    #if you need individual values
    for number in numbers:
       print number
    return sum(number)
```

And to call that functions from your `main.py` you can do :

```
import functions_file

print(functions_file.add(1,20)) #prints 21 if you're on py2 you don't need () for print

print(functions_file.add_all([1,2,3,4,5,6]))
#you pass parameters in list -> 21 is output
```

Comment: If I don't know how many parameters I'll be passing to the function each time is there a way to generalize it?

Comment: Well that your function should handle, and your question didn't ask that .. but I will include it in answer

Answer (score -2):

execfile(filename[, globals[, locals]])

Comment: ouch, that is not necessery